# Exclude minify from CSF/LFD

Tags: firewall, csf

I have currently installed minify on on of my websites however I am currently getting hammered with email from CSF/LFD.

Example:

```
   Time:   Fri Aug 10 13:10:03 2012 +0700
   File:   /tmp/minify_builder,index.php_f516d1c7cae9c3881406fd9a0ce69c38
   Reason: Script, file extension
   Owner:  -:- (504:501)
   Action: No action taken
```

What is the best way to have these ignored inside CSF? Some advice would be highyl appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define list of files that lfd directory watching will ignore in **/etc/csf/csf.fignore** configuration file. Having done it restart LFD daemon to apply changes.

In this particular case the following pattern should do the trick:

```
/tmp/minify\_builder*
```